# How to transform a DOM element on my site in a PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have a `div` inside my site containing some graphs using `SVG`. I want to prompt the browser to convert that `div` into a PDF, using the same algorithm it would use if the user asked to print the site, except restricted to only that `div`. I want to email and/or print the PDF.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TCPDF plug in for that.
Its widely used to create PDF from Html.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/

http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a div like this :

```
<div id='yourDIVid'><div>
```

You can make a function like this :

```
function savedivASpdf() {

   html2canvas(document.getElementById('yourDIVid'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("pdf_title.pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

You will need

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

and

http://pdfmake.org/#/

Download sources and add it like :

```
<script src="html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vfs_fonts.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
```